# How to use reader.GetDateTime(i) to get DateTime from sqlite database？

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
string sql = "select * from User where sUserName = '" + sUserName + "' AND sUserPassword = '" + sUserPassword + "'";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
    DateTime Time = reader.GetDateTime(0);
    System.DateTime timeNow_FromLocal = System.DateTime.Now; 
    if (timeNow_FromLocal < Time)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

I want to get `DateTime` from sqlite database to compare with system time, but I can not `reader.GetDateTime(0)` successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: @WangXinBoy09 what is the error you get? It could very well be that on position 1 there is no DateTime value.

Comment: the error is The string is not recognized as a valid DateTime. Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: @Rob I think you are right. But I have checked it, it is DateTime value. It is 2018-11-9 12:00:00 in my sqlite database.

Comment: @WangXinBoy09 Can you post the table structure?

Comment: @Rob I am so sorry that I use stackoverflow for the first time. I don't konw how to post the table structure to you.

Comment: @WangXinBoy09 post it as a text. I just want to see the layout of the table that's all.

Comment: Select the column you want in the query instead of '*' to ensure that your datetime column is in the first position.

Comment: @Rob Time   sUserName   sUserPassWord 2018-11-9 12:13:14   HangZhou   123456

Comment: @Rabban OK, I will try it. But GetDateTime(0) have shown that I am getting the value of column 0.

Comment: You can also try to get the DateTime as string and parse it by hand with `DateTime.Parse()`

Comment: @Rabban OK, thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DateTime Time = DateTime.Parse(reader["columnName"].ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have done it well with the help of you. I spent an afternoon working on my original way but spend little time to do it well by your way.Although I still have doubts about the original method, I intend to finish the project first and then study why it is not right.